# Unsure of parameter to store BIGNUM in char - BN_bn2bin()

Tags: c, binary, openssl, biginteger, bignum

I have the following code:

```
/*
* Special note about BN_bn2bin():
*      OpenSSL's BN_bn2bin() will truncate numbers at the front, but ISAKMP
* wants leading zero's instead.
*/
void _BN_encode(BIGNUM *bn, unsigned char *p, int len)
{
        int     pad;

        assert(bn);
        if ((pad = len - BN_num_bytes(bn))) {
                if (pad < 0) {
                        assert(1);
                        return;
                }
                memset(p, '\0', 1);
                BN_bn2bin(bn, p + pad);
        } else {
                BN_bn2bin(bn, p);
        }
}
```

And I gather that *bn is the BIGNUM I want to convert, *p is where I want to store it, but what should the argument len be?

I was also looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506619/trouble-with-openssls-bn-bn2bin-function) question which seems related. Any advice would be appreciated!

**Edit**

Would something along the lines of this be correct?

```
_BN_encode(bignum, bin_bignum, sizeof(char));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`len` is the length of the buffer pointed to by `p`.  The function pads out the converted bignum to `len` bytes (with zeroes, which doesn't change the mathematical value of the number represented).

That function appears to have a bug, by the way - I strongly suspect that the `memset()` call should be `memset(p, 0, pad);`.

Comment: Any idea what how it should be decided on / set?

Comment: Something like this?

 `char * buffer = malloc((BN_num_bytes(bignum)+1) * sizeof(char));
 _BN_encode(bignum, buffer, BN_bn2mpi(bignum, NULL));
 if (buffer == NULL) {
  fprintf(stderr, "buffer is NULL :(...\n");
 }`

Comment: If you did that then you would pass `BN_num_bytes(bignum) + 1` as the final argument to `_BN_encode()`.  There is no need to multiply by `sizeof(char)` - that is defined to be 1 by the standard.  You could just use `BN_num_bytes(bignum)` as well - the only requirement for a longer buffer is if the place you are passing the output to requires the bignum to be padded to a certain size.  If you don't have that requirement, you could just call `BN_bn2bin()` directly yourself.